# defroute not fired on page load

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame, secretary

I have application routes defined in my `routes.cljs` file in the root of `src/cljs/project/routes.cljs`.

```
(defn app-routes []
  (secretary/set-config! :prefix "#")

  (defroute
    "/" []
    (re-frame/dispatch [::events/set-active-panel :welcome-panel])))
  ; shortened for brevity
```

It is initialized in `core.cljs`

```
; required [portfolio-app.events :as events]
(defn ^:export init []
  (routes/app-routes)
  (re-frame/dispatch-sync [::events/initialize-db])
  (dev-setup)
  (mount-root))
```

It is dispatched to the `::events/set-active-panel` in `events.cljs`

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db
 ::set-active-panel
 (fn-traced [db [_ active-panel]]
   (assoc db :active-panel active-panel)))
```

And has the `:active-panel` subscription in `subs.cljs`

```
(re-frame/reg-sub
 ::active-panel
 (fn [db _]
   (:active-panel db)))
```

I subscribe to `:active-panel` in my `layout.cljs`

```
; required [portfolio-app.subs :as subs]
(defn panel []
  (let [active-panel (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/active-panel])]
    [:div
     "which panel? " @active-panel]))
```

`@active-panel` is `nil` when I access a page for the first time. The panel is dispatched only when I navigate through the pages. I know this worked initially. I can't see anything in my commits that could have broken it.

How do I get my `defroutes` to fire on page load as well as through site navigation?

Answer (score 0):

A couple guesses based on the code available:

- Are you calling `secretary/dispatch` on page load or just on subsequent navigation?
- Is your `::events/initialize-db` initializing the db after the `:active-panel` is properly set, causing your subscription to return `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have fallen victim to the re-frame "gotcha", where a namespace like `events` is elided in the compilation process since it is not listed in a `(:require ...)` form.  See [the Gotcha documentation](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/Basic-App-Structure.md#theres-a-small-gotcha) for more details.

To make the `(:require ...)` more explicit and harder to accidentally forget, I always wrap all of the `(reg-event-* ...)` calls inside a larger function that is initialized from the main program:

```
(ns demo.core  
  (:require 
     [demo.events :as events]
     [demo.subs :as subs]
     ...))

(defn app-start
  "Initiates the cljs application"
  []
  (events/define-all-events!)
  (subs/initialize-all)
  (configure-browser-routing!)
  ...)
```

and then:

```
(ns demo.events ...)
(defn define-all-events! []
  (reg-event-db ...)
  (reg-event-fx ...)
  ...)
```

I use a similar "wrap it in a function" technique for secretary/accountant routing and also for defining subscriptions (i.e. `reg-sub`).  For example:

```
(defn configure-browser-routing! []
  (println "configure-browser-routing - enter")

  (secretary/defroute "/all" []
    (println :secretary-route-all)
    (browser-nav-handler :all))
  (secretary/defroute "/active" []
    (println :secretary-route-active)
    (browser-nav-handler :active))
  (secretary/defroute "/completed" []
    (println :secretary-route-completed)
    (browser-nav-handler :completed))
  (secretary/defroute "/*" []
    (println ":secretary-route-all  *** default ***")
    (browser-nav-handler :all))

  (accountant/configure-navigation!
    {:nav-handler  (fn [path]
                     (t/spy :accountant--nav-handler--path path)
                     (secretary/dispatch! path))
     :path-exists? (fn [path]
                     (t/spy :accountant--path-exists?--path path)
                     (t/spy :accountant--path-exists?--result
                       (secretary/locate-route path)))})
  (println "configure-browser-routing - leave"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you by any chance have a repo I can look at so that I can see where I am going wrong? `init` won't mount when I wrap my functions and I suspect I must have one or two things misplaced or incorrectly wrapped. Much appreciated.

Comment: You can clone the following repo. Note that you need the `secretary-accountant` branch.  https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-enflame/blob/secretary-accountant/src/cljs/flintstones/core.cljs